# Making ellipsis to work in a LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists, ellipsis

I've been cracking my head here for several hours and I can't seem to find the answer to the issue.

How can I make a LI respect the size of it's parents and correctly use the ellipsis?
Situation is as follows:

```
<?PHP .... code code code ..?>
    <TABLE>
     <TR>
      <TD width=50%> <!-- other TD's with more data exist -->
       <DIV> <!-- Below this line is from another dynamically created file -->
        <TABLE WIDTH=100%>
         <TBODY>
          <TR>
           <TD> <!-- other TDs even with more data exist -->
            <DIV>
             <OL><?PHP code that echoes the following LIs from a DB ?>
               <LI> <!-- I want this LIs to fill text up to assigned width and then use ellipsis -->
              </LI>
             </OL>
           </DIV>
         </TD>
    ....
```

If I use the CSS:

```
  list-style-position:inside;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

It will make all the contents of the LI go pass the screen, one loooong line.
If I don't use this CSS, then the LI gets nicely multi-lined (which of course I don't want).

If I change the "WIDTH" of the parent DIV or the parent OL, then the text inside the LI gets cut off but still fills with whitespaces all the space that the full text would occupy.

Update: here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Fotofobia/kgrccckc/

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance that you could throw together a code snippet that would show what you're doing?  A jsfiddle or a snippet here within your post?

Comment: In your html, you have *"I want this LIs to fill text up to assigned width and then use ellipsis"* where's your assigned width? it works if you give it a width or max-width https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEgwJv

Comment: @KenH. I thought about throwing some fiddle here, but the code is distributed between several PHP files - I am filling DIVs and tables using javascript. That's why I tried to simplify it as much as I could

Comment: @MichaelCoker I wish It worked like that -- the first <td width=50%> should separate contents of the DIV, and the second <table width=100%> should take only the width of the containing DIV (which is 50% according to its TD parent) -- but it's not doing that at all...

Comment: Those widths aren't valid. Remove the `%`, but you shouldn't use inline styles anyways like that. the `width` attribute is obsolete in html5 https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html you should use CSS instead. Give them a class, and apply `width: 50%;` to the class.

Comment: @KenH. here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Fotofobia/kgrccckc/

Comment: @EdgarE.- one thing that I see in your jsfiddle post is that you are using the ID value multiple times. That is not a valid thing to do, although it does appear to be styling the `<li>` items accordingly.  Now I see that if I change the width of the `#li_info_units` style definition, it appears to make the line shorter and put the ellipsis at the end?  And I just attempted to take the width out of the settings for the `<li>` units and put it in the `.nav_info_units` and it looks like it works the same way - ellipsis are added? https://jsfiddle.net/kgrccckc/1/ - just saving that link.

Comment: @KenH.  it does, actually, I've had that result multiple times -- but why in the world ..the container gets resized horizontally with blank spaces up to the length of the original string?

Comment: @EdgarE.- the div, and probably the table and table row, etc. are block level elements, so they occupy the full width of their parent.  If you set the width of the `<li>` elements, the parent will not shrink to the same width.  At least that's the way I understand it.

Comment: @KenH. Great. So - correct me if I'm wrong - I can set the LI to 50% width and it will cover only half the width of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code update. By doing this you will create a kind of a stage, and all the content that "live" inside of it with now see the nowrap and overflow rules. I guess this will work. Please tell me something!! :)

```
list-style-position:inside;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 

// Add this to your code
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
```